# Connecting to MySql database on windows 2008 server via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a MySql db on a windows 2008 server via my php code, however I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110 in /home/---/---/--/collector.php on line 19
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110
```

this is my code:

```
mysql_connect("the.server.net", "mysqluser", "password") or die(mysql_error());
```

I have looked for solutions on the internet and I saw a lot of suggestions about enabling external connections, but this is not the problem as I am able to connect via MySql Workbench from a different computer.

I was hoping anyone has any suggestions/tips/ideas etc

Comment: have you tried connecting to the mysql server, from the box you are running the script on, using the cmdline mysql client with the same credentials?

Comment: Also you should really avoid using the mysql* functions rather use pdo or mysqli. See the warning in the php manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Error code 110 means connection timed out, so the remote server address and port is incorrect, or it or its firewall is blocking you.  Make sure none of those are the case, and verify that the address resolves correctly within PHP and hopefully make some progress.

Comment: Is workbench using another port other than 3306?